How do I write my SQL code on metabase with a "limit" table, without getting the "ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"
WITH limit_data AS (
    SELECT 
        l.amount,
        l.account,
        l.type,
        l.created_at,
        c.seller_id,
        c.verifier_id
    FROM limit l
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON l.account = c.customer_id
    WHERE l.type IN ('MPESA_PREDICTED', 'PROPOSED_KENYA_AGENT', 'MPESA_AUTO', 'MPESA_CHECKED', 'MANUAL')
)

I tried querying data from the limit table and customer table and I was expecting to get the type, created at, amount and the IDs. I got an error (ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit" )

Also, even when you correct that reserved keyword (limit to "limit"), that query will error. You need to follow a CTE with a select statement.

LIMIT is a reserved word. It's best not to use reserved words for object names (tables, columns, etc.) to avoid the errors like the one you see. However, if you must, quote the offending names:
SELECT 
  ...
FROM "limit" l

More info in the documentation.
